# Finding uninterrupted sub-arrays in Excel - Kadane's algorithm variation?

Tags: excel, kadanes-algorithm

Suppose you have an ordered, indexed list of positive values. These positive values are interrupted by 0 values. I want to determine if a consecutive sub-array exists which is not interrupted by 0 values and whose sum exceeds a certain threshold.

Simple example:

```
Index, Value
0   0
1   0
2   3
3   4
4   2
5   6
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   2
10  3
11  0
```

In the above example, the largest consecutive sub-array not interrupted by 0 is from index `2` to index `5` inclusive, and the sum of this sub-array is `15`.

Thus, for the following thresholds `20`, `10` and `4`, the results should be `FALSE`, `TRUE` and `TRUE` respectively.

Note I don't necessarily have to find the largest sub-array, I only have to know if any uninterrupted sub-array sum exceeds the defined threshold.

I suspect this problem is a variation of Kadane's algorithm, but I can't quite figure out how to adjust it.

The added complication is that I have to perform this analysis in Excel or Google Sheets, and I cannot use scripts to do it - only inbuilt formulas.

I'm not sure if this can even be done, but I would be grateful for any input.

Comment: Looking at this https://hackernoon.com/kadanes-algorithm-explained-50316f4fd8a6 , it should be fairly easy to implement it in Excel or Google sheets using a helper column, with an additional test that the running total should reset if the current element is zero. A single formula would be quite a challenge.

Comment: Actually since yours are all positive values, the algorithm just becomes 'if x[i]>0 sum=sum+x[i] else sum=0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
=B2
```

in c2

then put

```
=IF(B3=0,0,B3+C2)
```

in C3 and copy down.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

If you were looking for a Google sheets solution, try something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(sumif(A2:A,"<="&A2:A,B2:B)-vlookup(A2:A,{if(B2:B=0,A2:A),sumif(A2:A,"<="&A2:A,B2:B)},2)))
```

Assumes that numbers in column B start with zero: would need to add Iferror if not. It's basically an array formula implementation of @Gary's student's method.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the Google Sheets formula translated back into Excel. It gives you an alternative if you don't want to use Offset:

```
=MAX(SUMIF(A2:A13,"<="&A2:A13,B2:B13)-INDEX(SUMIF(A2:A13,"<="&A2:A13,B2:B13),N(IF({1},MATCH(A2:A13,IF(B2:B13=0,A2:A13))))))
```

(entered as an array formula).

**Comment**

Maybe the real challenge is to find a formula that works both in Excel and Google sheets because:

- Vlookup doesn't work the same way in Excel
- The offset/subtotal combination doesn't work in Google sheets
- The index/match combination with n(if{1}... doesn't work in Google sheets.

Comment: That's great, thank you @Tom Sharpe. This is definitely the easiest solution to this problem. I am slightly embarrassed that I didn't think of it myself.

Comment: Since I have to do this across 30+ columns I would prefer to avoid the helper column - I will post a solution that achieves this below.

Comment: You mentioned Google Sheets as an alternative: have added a Google Sheets solution to my answer. May I add a google sheets tag to your question as well?

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I haven't had a chance to test this yet but will do so soon and report back!

Answer (score 1):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, insure column **B** end with a 0.  Then in **C2** enter:

<strike>=IF(AND(B3=0,B2<>0),SUM(B$1:$B2)-MAX($C$1:C1),"")</strike>

and copy downwards:

[image]

Column **C** lists the sums of consecutive non-zeros.  In another cell enter something like:

```
=MAX(C:C)>19
```

where ***19*** is the criteria value.

You can avoid the "helper" column by using a VBA UDF.

**EDIT#1:**

Use this instead:

```
=IF(AND(B3=0,B2<>0),SUM(B$1:$B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

Comment: Should it be =IF(AND(B3=0,B2<>0),SUM(B$1:$B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"") @Gary's Student?

Comment: @TomSharpe  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student. A great solution that solves the problem. Thanks also for your suggestion in regards to avoiding the helper column. I have found another solution that achieves this without VBA which I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tom Sharpe and @Gary's Student for answering the question.

While I admittedly did not specify this in the question, I would prefer to achieve the solution without a helper column because I have to do this operation on 30+ successive columns. I just didn't think it was possible in Excel.

**[Full credit goes to user XOR LX on the Excelforum for coming up with this solution](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1313589-finding-uninterrupted-sub-arrays-in-excel-kadanes-algorithm-variation.html)**. It has blown my mind and took me the better part of an hour to wrap my head around, but it is certainly very creative. There is no way I could have come up with it myself. Re-posting it here for the benefit of everyone who is looking into this.

Copy and paste the table from my initial question into an empty Excel sheet such that the headers appear in `(A1:B1)` and the values appear in `(A2:B13)`.

Then enter this formula as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter), which gives the max of the sums of all the uninterrupted sub-arrays:

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,A2:A14,,-FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B13,A2:A13),IF(B3:B14=0,A2:A13,0))-1)))
```

Note the deliberate offset to include one additional row below the end of the dataset.

Comment: That looks very neat indeed - I will try it later to work out how it does it. I was vaguely thinking that frequency might help, but couldn't work out how, although I think a variation on @Gary's student's answer might also work as a single formula in google sheets and/or O365.